# Expect String but get a list of characters

Tags: python, list

This question has already be solved. But I did not do a awesome job illustrating my question. So I want to simplify it here:

```
string1 = "vege"
list1 = []
list1+=string1
# The output will be ["v","e","g","e"]
# If you want to add the word to the list, instead, you should use .append()
list1.append(string1)
```

Comment: Code is incomplete.

Comment: I am sorry I can make it easy here: '''asdf = []
asdf += "sean"
asdf''' it will give me a ["s","e","a","n"] and I expect a ["sean"]

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to achieve first before posting a long source snippet.

Comment: What does the function ```two_list_has_common_factor``` do? Provide source code

Comment: @SeanZhang1997 You need to `append`. `asdf.append("sean")`

Comment: @Pygirl. Thank you very much! I can't believe I forgot that function!

Comment: provide full code

Comment: @SeanZhang1997 You could've just written the first comment of yours as the question. All that source wasn't necessary when the problem is as small as that. When you're posting an incomplete source at the top, without explaining what it is that you're trying to achieve, there's a big chance people are not gonna read the whole question at all. These are very important things to consider when you're asking a question. Instead of lashing out on someone, try to understand why someone is saying whatever he/she is saying.

Comment: @anotherusername He wrote it at the end.  `why the new_category += key automatically turned the key into a list of characters?`

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: @Pygirl , As I said, he could've just written THAT for the question. All the other parts were unnecessary. When going through lists of questions, everyone expects something that is to-the-point. It'll also help him/her get answers much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to add a string to a list, it tries to iterate over every char in the string and append it to the string.

If your intention is to add a category to your new_category list, use append.

Instead of `new_category += key`, use `new_category.append(key)`